# Amazon Neptune: How to create custom vertex id in Python using tinkerpop/gremlinpython package?

Tags: python-3.x, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

As outlined here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html custom vertex ids can only be set with the unquoted `id` property, i.e., `g.addV('label1').property(id, 'customid')`. How can one accomplish this using the gremlinpython package? I see an `id` function in `gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal`, but I get an `UnsupportedOperationException` (as expected) when attempting to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just have to import `T` which is the class that hold the `id` and `label` members:

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
```

then use it as:

```
g.addV('label1').property(T.id, 'customid').iterate()
```

You can of course choose to import `id` from `T` so as to make the syntax synonymous with the example Gremlin in your question such that you may omit the `T` - some folks prefer that style.

It may be worth looking at the reference documentation for other [common imports](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#python-imports) that Gremlin uses.